# Flicker API does not work with simplFlickrSlidr

Tags: slider, flickr, nivo-slider

I really want to use this app: http://jquery.hellopablo.co.uk/simplFlickrSlidr/
But when I replaced my info., my newly created API and objectID (photo set) does not work (their supplied infos. work fine with the slider). I set my Flickr public already. Thank for your help. I am willing to supply my API and photoset.